# Is there a more efficient method to iterate over a matrix and perform calculations on specific columns?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, iteration, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix with 2 columns (matrix "X" with two features - feature0 and feature1) and variable number of rows.  For each sample (row in matrix) I want to compute an expanded row such that each row would be [feature0, feature1, feature0^2, feature1^2, feature0*feature1, 1].

I have written function below which does the job.

```
def expand(X):

    X_expanded = np.zeros((X.shape[0], 6))

    for i in range(X_expanded.shape[0]):
        for j in range(X_expanded.shape[1]):

            if j <= 1:
                X_expanded[i, j] = X[i, j]
            elif j == 2:
                X_expanded[i, j] = X[i, 0]*X[i, 0]
            elif j == 3:
                X_expanded[i, j] = X[i, 1]*X[i, 1]
            elif j == 4:
                X_expanded[i, j] = X[i, 0]*X[i, 1]            
            elif j == 5:
                X_expanded[i, j] = 1



    return X_expanded
```

The questions I have, is there a more efficient or "better way" of performing this calculation?  Seems cumbersome to me so would welcome any advice.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a simple function and stack them:

```
import numpy as np

def expanded(arr_2d):
    c1, c2 = arr.T
    return np.hstack([arr_2d, np.vstack([c1 ** 2, c2 ** 2, c1 * c2, np.ones(c1.shape[0])]).T])
```

Which is about 145x faster:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10000, 2))

%timeit expand(arr)

# 41 ms ± 3.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit expanded(arr)

# 282 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Validation check:

```
np.all(expand(arr) == expanded(arr))
# True
```